# Is this the right equation to compute the likelihood of a normal distribution at a point?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) gives this equation of maximization of the log-likelihood function.

${\displaystyle \ln {\mathcal {L}}(\mu ,\sigma ^{2})=\sum _{i=1}^{n}\ln f(x_{i}\mid \mu ,\sigma ^{2})=-{\frac {n}{2}}\ln(2\pi )-{\frac {n}{2}}\ln \sigma ^{2}-{\frac {1}{2\sigma ^{2}}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu )^{2}.}$

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55509481/11683992) gives an python implementation for the equation

this python code is adapted from that post to compute the likelihood at a point.

```
def llnorm(par, data):
    mu, sigma = par
    ll = math.log(2*math.pi*(sigma**2))/2 + np.sum(((data-mu)**2)/(2 * (sigma**2)))
    return ll
```

this [video](https://youtu.be/pYxNSUDSFH4?t=213) gives the value of the likelihood of a normal distribution with $\mu = 32, \sigma = 2.5$ at $x=34$, which is approximately equal to 0.12

I put the params in to my function

```
llnorm([32,2.5],34)
```

and got `2.155`, which is far from the example. Could someone help to analyze this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is log-likelihood.

To compute likelihood, please use this

[image]